# Dynamic type cast to the variable type

Tags: c++, types, casting

Suppose, I have a class, like:

```
struct A
{
  uint8_t f1;
  int16_t f2;
};
```

And I need to set it's members values from a memory buffer data, like:

```
uint8_t * memory=device.getBufferedDataFromDevice();

A a;
a.f1=*((uint8_t*)&memory[someAddress]);
a.f2=*((int16_t*)&memory[someOtherAddress]);
```

But I'd like to make it more flexible, and avoid the explicit type cast, to have a possibility to change the type in the declaration without changing the rest of the code. Of course, I could achieve it with something like:

```
memcpy((void*)&a.f1, (void*)&memory[someAddress], sizeof(A::f1));
```

But I'd also want to avoid calling a function for a simple types like 1-4 bytes long integers (which I have), as the simple assignment could be compiled to a single CPU instruction. Please advise, what is the c++ way to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: The compiler will very likely optimize out the call to `memcpy` and replace it with the single instruction you'd like to get.

Comment: Not sure about this. How  could it know what this particular function does? Is such a behaviour described in some standard? I'd rather want to control it explicitly, or at least be sure it would be replaced in any case with any compiler.

Comment: Yes, `memcpy` is part of the standard and has remained unchanged since the earliest versions of C.  The same can't be said of some of the other constructs you might come up with.

Comment: Seems you are trying to implement deserialization?

Comment: I meant a bit different aspect of such an optimization. Foo is linked by ld after the compilation, and compiler has no idea about it. it could be linked against my own nonstandard non stdlib implementation and such a replacement is quite dangerous, as compiler has no idea what real foo does. Guessing by the name/sig is inappropriate because of that. That’s why i doubt such a replacement is really possible.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin it can be called like that, of course.

Comment: @BbIKTOP Sure if you swap to an alternative standard library that the compiler is not shipped with, then the compiler probably will not optimize it; But if compiled with the library that shipped with the compiler then it is probably going to take advantage of a whole host of optimizations that have been developed over the years. Why even assume anything. Just try it and look at the code. I mean copying over 4 byes of memory is not exactly hard to optimize into a single instruction.

Comment: @MartinYork i doubt it could, because there’s no way for the compiler to realize at the compile time what libraries will be linked. I could, like, compile everything today and then link it a day after on another computer.That’s why, i suppose, such an optimization is unlikely possible

Comment: @BbIKTOP how about looking at the assembly your compiler generated, instead of trying to second-guess

Comment: What do you mean by "anything"? I expect the compiler supports standrds, not more and not less

Comment: @BbIKTOP IF you link a library where the size of the object has changed on a different day there are a lot more things that will break than this optimization. C++ has an expectation that all objects are a specific size. They can't change in size, so the compiler has to know the size at compile time. If the library that your linking has a different size for the object then you have done something wrong and broken the ABI. This optimization is trivial. What you think is irrelevant, stop guessing and look at what the compiler does.

Comment: @MartinYork please understand how compiler and linker works. Sizes are completely irrelevant in this particular case, don’t understand why did you mention it at all. There are header files that contain declarations for libraries, with sizes, number and size (type) of parameters and linkage. I’d advise you to read the standard, especially p.6.6, hope it will clarify the things for you. According to the standard, you cannot rely on this “optimization” and it’s sad so many people here advise to rely on it just because “it was working fir me”, which is definitely very wrong.

Comment: @BbIKTOP When quoting the standard, please use the standard way of doing it. The version and the section name and the paragraph. Preferably, quote what you want me to read. Sure, optimizations can be turned off. Sure, not all compilers implement them all. Why I mention size. There are only three parameters to memcpy. Two addresses and a size. If the compiler knows the size, that size is static (known at compile time) and small. Optimization is trivial. The size of **ALL** objects are known at compile time (don't need to wait for linking). So size `struct A` is know at compile time.

Comment: @MartinYork i cannot quote here because of the comments size )). As i told you, start on p 6.6. I explained you so many times about functions, read about linkages and you could understand how it works

Comment: @BbIKTOP nobody has told you to rely on anything. We were simply commenting on your personal incredulity that this could not happen. You were wrong it can and does happen. Do we say it always happen. No. Do we way say rely on it. No. Do we consider it best practice to use standard algorithms/functions rather than trying to write your own optimized one. Absolutely. Even if the your compiler does not do it now it may do it in the future. Best to follow best practice. The compiler is (usually) good at (Micro optimization) humans are (usally) good at (algorithmic optimization).

Comment: Best of luck in your quest to understand the compiler.

Comment: @MartinYork please read some beginners book about what compiler does and what linker is intended for. You definitely should clarify it for you. Then you could proceed to the p6.6 of the standrad. Have a nice day

Comment: @BbIKTOP For future reference, you should quote the standard like this:  in [`n4885`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4885.pdf) Section [basic.link]. The section numbers can change between versions and are not reliable over time. So you should use the standardized names `[basic.link]`. Usually you would also point out a particular paragraph with in a section rather than 4 pages to prove a point.

Comment: you should never rely on "generated assembly", or any other particular case, as a proof of something. It depends on declaration, according to a standard. Ask question, and me, orsomeone else, could explain how it works. You could also read about what linkage is and how compiler and linker build a binary in any beginners c/c++ book

Comment: removed my comments because Yakk's answer and comments below explain the same thing better.

Comment: Yakk is obviously wrong and it’s easy to check both in standard and in practice. I really have no time to explain it in the comments, although I’d like to give you some knowledges about this, comments format is not suitable for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a code similar to this:

```
template<typename T>
void mymemcopy(T* a, void* b) {
    memcpy((void*)a, b, sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
constexpr void mymemcopy(T** a, void* b) {
    *a = static_cast<T*>(b);
}

constexpr void mymemcopy(int* a, void* b) {
    *a = *(int*)b;
}

constexpr void mymemcopy(unsigned char* a, void* b) {
    *a = *(unsigned char*)b;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b =10;
    mymemcopy(&a, &b);

    double a1, b1 =10;
    mymemcopy(&a1, &b1);

    unsigned char a2, b2 =10;
    mymemcopy(&a2, &b2);

    unsigned char *a3, *b3 =nullptr;
    mymemcopy(&a3, &b3);
}
```

I somehow think your case use is for embedded programming and I'm not expert. I know in embedded programming you need to decrease both memory usage and code. But you are asking will increase code size obviously.

Comment: Yes, it is for embedded and for different toolchains/compilers, that's why I need to make it shorter, faster and standard, as every cycle/byte counts. I currently implemented it in the similar way using inline, but i'm not sure inline will work with all toolchains I have to use. I am looking for somethilg like ```*a.f1=(typeof(A::f1*))&buffer[123];```

Comment: @BbIKTOP you can write specialization for the one you mentioned too, but that one is a move not copy. So logic will differ and I don't advice it. In addition, what you are asking increases total code size in exchange of better speed, you can not have all together. I add pointer version too.

Comment: @BbIKTOP I added pointer version too, but since it somehow changes logic of code, I personally against using it.

Comment: In the terms of data in the memory, it's copying, that's why this function named "memcpy".
Sure, such an approach will definitely work, I have implemented almost the same with 1,2,4 and 8 bytes variants which is a bit bulky, of course. Looks like there's no better way, so I will accept your answer as a straight, ponderous and working one )) Thank you!

Comment: `memcpy` is not `constexpr`, so first overload is wrong.

Comment: @Jarod42 At first I didn't add constexpr to first one because I thought so. but when I added, code compiled without error and I don't know why. Since I saw it compiled, I added it to answer, but I guess it is better to remove it.

Comment: With `template`, it is harder to diagnose.

Comment: @Jarod42 true, but it is really strange bug. I removed it anyway. I guess I add it as another  post to see if people know anything about it or not.

Comment: Note that in some versions of C++ the above casts make your program ill-formed, ndr.  You czn copy memory over basic tyoes, but casting arbitrary memory and assigning is not legal.  The most likely problem of the program being ill formed is misaligned memory access; it usually works, despite being illegal, except for that.

Answer (score 5):

`memcpy` is fully understood by every modern C++ compiler, and there is not going to be an actual function call unless you take its address, store that in a pointer, then confuse the compiler enough that it no longer knows the pointer points at `memcpy`.

Or, you know, turn off optimizations.

```
memcpy((void*)&a.f1, (void*)&memory[someAddress], sizeof(A::f1));
```

there is neither reason to cast to `void*`, nor use dangerous C-style casts, here.

```
std::memcpy(&a.f1, &memory[someAddress], sizeof(a.f1));
```

this is a standards-compliant way to move memory that represents data of the same type as `a.f1` over `a.f1`, assuming `a.f1` is trivially copyable.  (Note I used the same token sequence -- `a.f1` -- for both the written-to stuff and the size.)

The compiler will optimize this into appropriate assembly, and there will be no function-call overhead.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/MsEvW86sa), you can see the generated assembly.

Now, you may object "but there is no guarantee!".

The C++ standard does not include a guarantee that `a+b` won't be implemented as a loop `int r = 0; for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i){++r;} for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i){++r;}`.

You cannot presume your C++ compiler is hostile.

Existing C++ compilers optimize calls to `memcpy`.  Writing code assuming it won't happen is a waste of time.

You can also write a slightly safer memcpy

```
template<class Dest>
void memcpyT( Dest* dest, void const* src ) {
  static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Dest> );
  memcpy( dest, src, sizeof(Dest) );
}
```

which I included as an alternative in the above live example.

Comment: I checked it with one of my toolchains and clearly see there's a foo call: ```11: 0008e0         callx8 a8```
Could you please explain, how would it behave in case I'd link it with another stdlib, for example with the one that swaps bytes during copy process? How could compiler understand what foo will be linked later?

Comment: @BbIKTOP What is your toolchain, and compiler flags?  And what is `foo`?  `memcpy`'s behavior is defined by the C++ standard, not by what any particular library does.  A compiler that uses a stdlib with a memcpy that doesn't do what memcpy does is not a compiler of C++.  A compiler that sees a call to `memcpy` can, under the standard, ignore what the library says and just do what it should do.

Comment: checked with xtensa32, have no idea how to check flags set by pio

Comment: @BbIKTOP Googling I get that this is gcc based?

Comment: Please, share a link to the standard.

Comment: @BbIKTOP [tag:C++20] standard (draft, official version requires $): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf - it is a long read, and probably won't help.

Comment: This one - yes. Didn't try others yet

Comment: @BbIKTOP xtensa32 -- what version of gcc are you using?  Is it a debug or release build?  Debug builds will do piles of work to make stepping through it easier, including actually calling memcpy

Comment: Again. As I understand, compiler should compile. It cannot replace foo (functions) calls because it is not known what exact function will be linked. There are two independent processes in building a binary - one is compiling, which actually isthe object code generation, and second is linking. It would be a very bad practice if compiler would assume anything about the linking stage it is not responsible to in any way

Comment: @BbIKTOP You misunderstand.  The standard library and its behavior are mandated by the standard.  If this is implemented by linking, it can link.  But the compiler is free to not use linking to implement it.  If you look at my godbolt link, the memcpy was gone, and no linking was done.  This is compliant and optimal C++.  Now, it is possible your toolchain isn't very good, and this optimization is blocked.  That does suck.  Try checking a release mode build of your code.

Comment: this is what I'm asking for. Is it defined in the standard somewhere, that compiler could not use linking when it explicitly told to do that by calling a function with () operator?

Comment: @BbIKTOP You are wrong if you think `memcpy(&a, &b, 7)` is explicitly telling C++ to use linking.  It is a common misconception that the naive mapping you have in your head between C++ program code to assembly is what C++ is defined as doing.  It is not.  The C++ standard library defines compilation units, and the body of the C++/C standard library is not a compilation unit, the fact that is how your tool chain works is an implementation detail outside of the standard.  The C/C++ standard described what calling `memcpy` does, it does not address it being linked or anything else.

Comment: @BbIKTOP But this is far beyond the scope of your question.  Feel free to verify the memcpy goes away in an optimized build in your toolchain, or not and do something else.

Comment: I supposed, () operator explicitly tells compiler to call a function. Could you please share where did you get such a strange idea it is not so

Comment: Ok,  it depends on declaration. Read § 6.6